# Whatchamacallit: You know how there are breadcrumbs and sliders and whatnot

Tags: website-design, design, theme

What do you call it when a web site (especially corporate/retail) has a series of rows with thumbnails, each with a little caption/description beneath explaining some benefit or feature of a product or service. Is there a name for this?

I'm building a theme that incorporates this kind of design and I was hoping there is some kind of shorthand for this design feature.

If you don't know what I'm talking about, check out one of the links below.

http://themeforest.net/item/revolution-minimalist-business-html-template/full_screen_preview/2295335

http://themes.two2twelve.com/preview?theme=freshserve

Answer (score 4):

The information that is below the thumbnail (giving details about the image) is usually just code that is written for each individual thumbnail.

You can use [LightBox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to show an image of the thumbnail in front of all of a pages content. It is known as a 'LightBox', you will find many sites that use different variants of this. Almost every one doing this is going to be using a set of [jQuery](http://jquery.com) functions along with some custom CSS.

Comment: "Lightbox" is the name for the popup-like display, not the actual thumbnails. Though I don't think the list of thumbnails has its own name.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat -- You are right. I have changed my answer to reflect this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Our wireframes usually refer to those as "touts" or "content highlights".

If they are getting very fancy and have more than will fit on the page then we might put them in a carousel to show the first few, the scroll them out for the next set.